# Como ter resultados booleanos da interação de duas listas?

Tags: python-3.x

Como ter resultados booleanos da interação de duas listas?

Ou seja:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] 
b = [2,4]
```

para cada item em `a` que pertença a `b` retorne `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode iterar dessa maneira:

```
for x in a:
    print(x in b)
```

Ou assim:

```
for x in a:
    if x in b:
        print(x) # ou print(x in b)
```

Se quiser guardar os items que são comuns entre as listas, em uma nova lista faz assim:

```
   c = set(a).intersection(set(b))
   c = list(c)
```

Comment: Olá Iron Man. Muito obrigado pela sugestão, inclusive é a que aparentemente vou ter que usar. Achei que existiria uma biblioteca ou que o pandas teria uma forma mais fácil de fazer.